# Problemas con Enlace de confirmación de correo electrónico en Asp.net Core y SenGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

El enlace de confirmación que me llega a la cuenta de correo electrónico debería dirigirme a la pagina de ConfirmEmail.cshtml, pero me dirige a otra pagina que es la de Register.cshtml.

Ruta del enlace que me llega al correo:

> https://localhost:44312/Account/Register?userId=e49a01e4-db71-4cbe-8398-b35e3f537d16&code=CfDJ8A7zs7RxdEZPu5TBisMjgsFPsV4DAz0JuVskRf56hIWgNTrN5Zq9knfNygtKP%2BxIF5Q2TjwzlWipbfgjcAYrOCRmzFc8cZh5i9a5IamKrfxCf9wILyMLxuy2opRJ7crV0ygKZy1HpgJHJErben73oapmPkx8sl4bvOlZ8%2BL%2BjVvhBBFzpJgA4PcoterxzjPDf%2F7sBcmmMYvZKI2wayb1gT%2FRFBkhp09IlG2Oe%2FLOW2ejNjZYbnhko6J8rn8ekbIpKA%3D%3D&page=%2FAccount%2FConfirmEmail

Este es el Método Register, donde se guarda  la nueva cuenta de usuario y se envía el enlace al correo para la confirmación

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded) {

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                     "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                     pageHandler: null,
                     values: new {  userId= user.Id, code = code},
                     protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm your email",
                $"Please confirm you account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>Clicking here</a>");

                //Linea que permite registrar una cuenta email, sin confirmar
                //await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent : false);
                _logger.LogInformation("USer created a new account with password");

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
```

Comment: ¿Has colocado breakpoints para revisar cómo se forma la url?

Comment: Al hacer el debug, he verificado que el contenido de callbackUrl es la misma ruta que he citado al inicio de este post.

Comment: Por lo que me lleva a pensar el problema esta en lafuncion de Url.Page(), pero no hallo como solucionarlo

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los parámetros de Url.Page ("este primero",... )?

Comment: Pareciera un problema de configuración de paquetes. Si presionas f12 sobre Url.Page(), que metadata te muestra? El usual debería de ser Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=...

Comment: El primer parametro de Url.Page es la ruta al que me deberá redirigir cuando el usuario confirme su cuenta de email, y values: contiene el id del usuario y el token de confirmacion

Comment: con respecto al metadata
 ensamblado Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

Comment: Los parametros de la url que nos muestras no conciden con el codigo del action, la url define un userId y page.
Mientras que el action espera un model RegisterViewModel que no se que propiedades tendra y un returnUrl que es opcional.
No veo que resuelva en ese action por la url que proporcionas

Comment: @LeandroTuttini la url define el userId, code, y page.
y en el RegisterViewModel, tengo las propiedades de Email, Password y ConfirmPassword, y lo que contiene el metodo Register lo he obtenido del manual de Microsoft, en la sección de Account Confirmation

Comment: Encontré una solución, fue crear un método en una nueva clase: Url.EmailConfirmationLink().
Les dejo el link del ejemplo:
https://github.com/TanvirArjel/AspNetCoreMvcIdentity/blob/master/AspNetCoreMvcIdentity/Extensions/UrlHelperExtensions.cs